# rails 4.1.6 form_for coffeescript on multiple views not working

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, coffeescript, submit, form-for

I can get my coffeescript error messages to appear with one view (/users/new.html.erb):

```
<h1> Sign up! </h1>
<%= form_for (@user) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :email %><p class="error email-error"></p>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>       

  <%= f.submit "Sign Up", class: 'btn' %>   
<% end %>
```

and one coffeescript file (/users.js.coffee):

```
ready = ->
  $('form').submit ->

    $('.error').text ''    
    email = $('#user_email').val()

    if email == ''
      $('.email-error').text 'Please enter your email.'

    false
  return

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

BUT when I try to add a second view (/sessions/new.html.erb) the error messages for both forms won't display:

```
<h1> Log In </h1>
<%= form_for(:session, url: login_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.label :email %><p class="error email-error"></p>
  <%= f.email_field :email, :id => "session_email" %>

  <%= f.submit "Log In", class: 'btn' %>    
<% end %>
```

and coffeescript file (/sessions/js.coffee):

```
main = ->

  $('form').submit ->

    $('.error').text ''    
    email = $('#session_email').val()

    if email == ''
      $('.email-error').text 'Please enter your email'

    false
  return

$(document).ready(main)
$(document).on('page:load', main)
```

I know that ultimately the coffeescript is compiled into one file by rails so it will not know which 'form' I am referencing. But when I've tried to add id tags to the forms, I can't even get one form to work. I've been stuck for 2 days on this and can't figure it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: No it's not. I messed up when spacing it on stackoverflow. It's fixed now. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: You don't want multiple listeners for `submit` so add a `class="login"` to the forms and bind `$('form.login').submit(...)` globally, you'll probably need to restructure the forms so that they're structurally the same and then use `$(this).find(...)` to find the form elements in the handler. You also need to be more specific about what "not working" means.

Comment: You're right, I shouldn't have used "not working." I've edited that. I added a class to the forms and .unbind() ended up being the winning function. Thanks for taking the time to comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of "mu is too short" I was able to get the error messages to appear on both forms. The problem was that .submit() was binding to one form and preventing it from binding to the second. Adding a .unbind() fixed this:

```
ready = ->
  $('form.new_user').submit ->

    $('.error').text ''    
    email = $('#user_email').val()

    if email == ''
      $('.email-error').text 'Please enter your email.'

    $('form').unbind('submit')  
    false
  return

$(document).ready(ready)
$(document).on('page:load', ready)
```

AND the second coffeescript file:

```
main = ->

  $('form.s_login').submit ->

    $('.error').text ''    
    s_email = $('#session_email').val()

    if s_email == ''
      $('.email-error').text 'Please enter your email'

    $('form').unbind('submit')  
    false
  return

$(document).ready(main)
$(document).on('page:load', main)
```